# How to control my account navigation Links?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

Why the following links are displayed in **My account** section even user not been subscribed/registered for this features and also they are not been used commonly by the users in the website.

```
Billing Agreements
Recurring Profiles
My Applications
```

It would be good if it can be displayed when user has subscribed/registered to those features in the website.

Because as I see in my day to today development, many clients gets confused and ask for removing this links.

There are other links like the following which are very commonly to be used  by any registered customer.

```
Account Dashboard
Account Information
Address Book
My Orders
```

Comment: Are you looking for Magento 2 or Magento 1.9 answer? Or both? Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for magento 1 now, but my concern here is why the magento is not handling or providing  any configuration from admin side to control this links. thanks for your reply @MaxPronko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer for Magento 2.

In order to remove any link for Customer Account a layout xml file should be used. You may check vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml file where Billing Agreement link is added:

```
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">paypal/billing_agreement</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Billing Agreements</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

For this link to be removed you may use write the following customer_account.xml file in your custom theme with "remove" attribute specifying block name "customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link":

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true" />
</body>
```

All other links might be removed in a same safe and non-conflict way.

Comment: thanks @MaxPronko for your answer, actually I'm concern regarding why the Magento not providing the configurations from Magento admin side as the links specified in my post are not generically used by common user.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Go to ( yourPackage/YourTemplate/customer/account/navigation.phtml )

**Step 2**: Replace the below line

```
<?php $count = count($links); ?>
```

with

```
<?php $_count = count($_links); /* Add or Remove Account Left Navigation Links Here -*/
      unset($_links['account']); /* Account Info */     
      unset($_links['account_edit']); /* Account Info */            
      unset($_links['tags']); /* My Tags */
      unset($_links['invitations']); /* My Invitations */
      unset($_links['reviews']);  /* Reviews */
      unset($_links['wishlist']); /* Wishlist */
      unset($_links['newsletter']); /* Newsletter */
      unset($_links['orders']); /* My Orders */
      unset($_links['address_book']); /* Address */
      unset($_links['enterprise_customerbalance']); /* Store Credit */
      unset($_links['OAuth Customer Tokens']); /* My Applications */
      unset($_links['enterprise_reward']); /* Reward Points */
      unset($_links['giftregistry']); /* Gift Registry */
      unset($_links['downloadable_products']); /* My Downloadable Products */

      unset($_links['recurring_profiles']); /* Recurring Profiles */
      unset($_links['billing_agreements']); /* Billing Agreements */
      unset($_links['enterprise_giftcardaccount']); /* Gift Card Link */
?>
```

Comment: Links have to be removed from layout xml files.

Comment: Yes links has to be managed from the layout files, anyhow thanks for your answer @lalitmohan